# Rails order tasks by date conditionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements

Dear Programming Angels,

I am ordering tasks on a project page. Tasks are required to have a date_from but not a date_to. Now I am ordering tasks by date_to (as instructed by superiors) which puts tasks with only a date_from at the end of the list.

Goal:

If a task does not have a date_to I want it to be placed into the list by date_from while still ordering the rest by date_to.

show method in controller:

```
@project_tasks = @project.project_tasks.where.not(project_task_type_id: nil).order('project_tasks.date_to')
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most SQL dialects define `COALESCE`, which returns the first non-`NULL` argument. To order using `COALESCE`, you need to `SELECT` an aliased value then order by it.

Thus, to order `@project_tasks` by `date_to` if not `nil` and `date_from` otherwise:

```
@project_tasks = @project.project_tasks.select("project_tasks.*, COALESCE(project_tasks.date_to, project_tasks.date_from) AS date_to_order")
  .where.not(project_task_type_id: nil).order('date_to_order ASC')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was over my head. Greatly appreciated!